# The unit of area in R package {UScensus2010}

Tags: r

I am using the {UScensus2010} package in R and trying to get the area for each county. I found the areaPoly() in the package. Does anyone know the unit of the area? Is it square mile?

Thank you.

Comment: Type `?functionName` to find documentation for a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using US Census data, this is from the explanation of the dataset that UScensus2010 links to:

> Land area measurement in square meters. The accuracy of the area
>   measurement is limited by the inaccuracy inherent in the mapping of
>   the various boundary features in the Census Bureau’s geographic
>   database. Land area includes areas classified as intermittent water,
>   swamps, and glaciers, which appear on census maps and in the Census
>   Bureau’s geographic database as hydrographic features. Square miles
>   can be derived by dividing square meters by 2,589,988. See Appendix A,
>   “Geographic Terms and Concepts,” for definition of this field.

http://www.census.gov/prod/cen2010/doc/sf1.pdf

If you are still unsure, pick your home county and check it against the area that wikipedia or the official county website claims.

Comment: I was looking through the documentation and the package code and couldn't find reference to the units anywhere.  Strange that it wouldn't be included.